# Java - TCP exception

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP Server and Client both written in Java and running on separate machines on Rhel 5.3 with jdk1.6. I have handled pretty much all the methods i could find to detect a disconnection on the "Server".

Following is a snippet of the Server code

```
private void listenforConnection() {
    try {

        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
        socket.setSoTimeout(5);

        bosTcpOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        bisTcpInStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        log("New connection accepted from " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
        sendHeartBeatsToClient();

    } catch (IOException ie) {
        log("Listener IOException : " + ie.getMessage());
    }
}           

private void sendHeartBeatsToClient() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            long lngCurrentMillis=System.currentTimeMillis() ;
            if ((lngCurrentMillis - lngLastSentMessageTime) >= 5000) {
                byte[] bHeartBeat = getHeartBeatMessage();
                bosTcpOutStream.write(bHeartBeat);
                bosTcpOutStream.flush();
                lngLastSentMessageTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                log("Heartbeat sent.");
            } else {
                try {
                    if (bisTcpInStream.read() == -1) {
                        log("Read Input Stream returned -1");
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException se) {
                    //Do nothing as i am not expecting the client to send anything.
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log("Read Input Stream error - " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        disconnectClientAndCloseSocket();
        log("IO Exception" +e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        disconnectClientAndCloseSocket();
        log("Thread interrupted terminating." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have also modified the tcp-keepalive kernel parameters on the "Server" machine as below:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=2
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=1
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=2
```

Now when i am simulating a disconnection by unplugging the network cable of the Client machine(after it has established the connection and received the initial data from the Server), I am seeing two different outcomes which i am unable to understand:-

1. If i unplug the cable after 10 to 15 seconds of successful client connection. On the "Server" I receive an IO Exception with "no route to host" after **10 minutes** of unplugging the cable.
2. If i unplug the cable after 60 or so seconds of successful client connection. On the "Server" an IO exception is thrown with "Connection timed out" **within 10 seconds**. This is valid behavior keeping in mind the keep alive settings.

I have tried this a couple of times and i always get the same result.

What i don't understand is why the first outcome takes 10 minutes and it doesn't behave like the second outcome. Am i missing something?

Comment: During those 10 minutes do you get any log messages??

Comment: I dont understand your questions, are you asking about exceptions?

Comment: I'm talking about `log("Heartbeat sent.");` during the 10 minutes.

Comment: You don't need keep-alive *and* a heartbeat *and* a read timeout, and 5ms is ridiculously short for a read timeout.

Comment: Why do you say 5ms is short for a read timeout?

Comment: ahmed yes the hearbeats are logged every 5 seconds (as if the client is connected).